# bootstrap toogle between 'collapse' and 'collapse in' based on device

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have collapse panel default "collapse in" (expand) it working good, but I would like to set "collapse" (shrink) for mobile/tab, how can I achieve? is there any inbuilt feature in bootstrap?

```
<div class="container hero-spacer">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title fontboldx">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"></span> Information</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>here details will come</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image: Default]

For mobile/tab I would like get output as shown in below  image

[image]

Comment: Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18109627/auto-close-bootstrap-accordion-panel-when-switch-to-mobile-screen-size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution using by simple JS as follows..

**Following code has to be placed after objects created** (better place before body close `</body>`  )

```
<script>
if ((screen.width>=1024) && (screen.height>=768)) {
 var x = document.getElementById("collapseOne");
 x.className = "panel-collapse collapse in"; 
}
else {
var x = document.getElementById("collapseOne");
 x.className = "panel-collapse collapse"; 
}
</script>
```